# How can I update instances of a text template after changing the master template?

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x, motion

I've got 20 or so text items in my timeline, all using a text template called `Bookmark` that I created in Motion. I want to modify the text template in Motion and have the changes propagate through to each of the text items that are already in the timeline. Is that possible?

I'm using Final Cut Pro 10.1.2 and Motion 5.1.1.

Comment: I found documentation that shows how to make this work in FCP v.7, but FCP v.10 doesn't work the same way: https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=77%26section=3%26tasks=true

Comment: I found this page discussing the problem you're having, and a potential workaround, but I couldn't get it to work in 10.1.2  http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/344/16556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't currently supported. Your text items will preserve the state from when they were first added. So you're stuck doing it manually. It's number 4 on the list of top requested features for the next update though and Apple seems to be aware of this site, or they've just been reading minds the last few updates- http://fcpx.tv/top.html

One thing that has helped me though is that you can drag your new Motion titles on top of the old ones already on your timeline, hit "replace", and it should retain the original text of the old title.

Comment: As well as the drag, drop, and replace workflow that you described, I found that it's also possible to click an existing title in the timeline, then double click the corresponding template in the browser to replace the old styles with the new ones while preserving text.